# netezza passing variables

Tags: sql, netezza

hi am trying to pass values for my variable in sql using a run_nzodbc script,

run_nzodbc /development/df2/dfr/sql/adhoc/sriram/gen.sql -v **condition =PROD.USC_CODE IN (12000,12001)**>/development/df2/data01/sriram/df2_astrazeneca_seroquel_mthly_01160044DPT.log 2>/development/df2/data01/sriram/df2_astrazeneca_seroquel_mthly_01160044DPT.err &

gen.sql

create table xxx
as

(
select * from abc as a
where 
a.string =:condition
);

instead of condition i have to replace a string which contains space in between which is passed as variable while running the query.
but when the value is passed it gets truncated after an instance of space occurs,
i have tried passing the value enclosed in single and double quotes.
please let me know is there a way to pass string values with space in between as a vriable

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about how the bash shell handles environment variables rather than how the nzsql CLI handles them.  Please include the portion of the gen.sql code that references the environment variable so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
nzsql -Atv "condition='1 with space'" -c "select :condition"
```

I would imagine that the `run_nzodbc` command would work the same.

Comment: thanks i could pass strings in nzsql,is it the same way to pass date parameter in nzsql as nzodbc because i am getting a bad external time stamp representation  error ?  this is the script used,                        nzsql  -A -t -F '~' -f /development/df2/dfr/sql/adhoc/sriram/forest.sql -v MTH_END_DT='2015-12-31' -o  /development/df2/data01/sriram/forest.dat &

Comment: You didn't double quote the -v argument in the code above. Try `... -v "MTH_END_DT='2015-12-31'" ...`

Comment: nzsql -Atv "condition=PROD.USC_CODE IN (24200,31440,37620,52151,52152,52153,52158,85000,52159,31511,31200)" -v a=2 -v "MTH_END_DT='2015-12-31'" -f /development/df2/dfr/sql/adhoc/sriram/gen.sql -o /development/df2/data01/sriram/data.dat                                                               even i tried it still it shows bad time stamp

Comment: Your statement of `gen.sql`'s content above does not at all mention `MTH_END_DT`. In addition, you change about 5 things from the last time you posted a comment. Since apparently you didn't before, post the *entirety* of `gen.sql` in your question, as ScottMcG already asked.

Comment: path: /development/df2/dfr/sql/adhoc/sriram/test_1.sql         query: select * from prod_rx_dim..prescriber_dim pres
where
PRES.MTH_END_DT=':MTH_END_DT'
and :condition;

Comment: script used :nzsql -Atv "condition=pres.prescriber_id in (24200,31440,37620,52151,52152,52153,52158,85000,52159,31511,31200)" -v "MTH_END_DT='2015-12-31'" -f /development/df2/dfr/sql/adhoc/sriram/test_1.sql>/development/df2/dfr/sql/adhoc/sriram/gen.log 2>/development/df2/dfr/sql/adhoc/sriram/gen.err  -o /development/df2/data01/sriram/test_data.dat &

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @jeremytwfortune i found that when we pass date parameter we need to pass  the variable enclosed by both single and double quotes ,  select * from orders where ord_dt = :order_date
then one can do this as follows: nzsql -v order_date="'01-Jun-08'" -f sql.2